# Holonomy of a Leaf

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, projection, foliations, holonomy

**Geometry, Dynamics And Topology of Foliations A First Course**. **Bruno Scardua**, **Carlos Arnoldo Morales Rojas**. Page **59**.

1. What are $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$?
2. How are $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ defined?
3. In general, how to define the projection along the plaques?
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Sigma_i$ is the quotient of $U_i$ by the relation defined by $x\simeq y$ if $x,y\in U_i$ and they are contained in the same leaf. $\pi_i$ is the projection onto the space of leaves $\Sigma_i$, that is the map which sends $x$ to its equivalence class.

Comment: Is it true that the dimension of $\Sigma_i =$ the co-dimension of the foliation?

Comment: yes, it is true, just think about a quotient of vector spaces, locally it is equivalent.